# How do I make an SOQL Query with Spaces in Column Names?

Tags: python, salesforce, soql

I'm trying to make an SOQL query using the `simple_salesforce` python package. I'm having a bit of trouble querying columns which have spaces in the column names:

```
sf.query_all("SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE `Lead Source`=Calculator (Website)")
```

I'm trying to use the conventional SQL syntax of dealing with pesky column names (I have also tried `[]` brackets) but I keep getting a `SalesforceMalformedRequest`.

I want to get a python dict which contains the IDs, Names and Emails of any leads that have a lead source of 'Calculator (Website)'.

I don't have privileges to change the column names, so any help on how to query, or how to access the column names in some other way, would be a lot of help!

Comment: In [ANSI SQL it would be "quoted identifier"](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/crefsqlj1003454.html). No idea if this helps for SOQL, especially as MySQL uses \`quoted identifier\`.

Comment: Is the error, perhaps on `Calculator (Website)`? That text / char data should probably be quoted, eg. MySQL identifiers - `"SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE \`Lead Source\` = 'Calculator (Website)'"` or, ANSI identifiers - `"SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE \"Lead Source\" = 'Calculator (Website)'"` (escaping the quotes is merely an artifact of appearing in a Python string literal; the `"""..."""` form is useful here)

Comment: There is no mention of quoted identifiers in the [sparse] [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) although it does say about a fieldExpression: ["*The name of a field in the specified object. Use of single or double quotes around the name will result in an error.*"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm). Perhaps column identifiers are normalized first? eg. `Lead__Source`? (It seems like SF likes to mangle field names..)

Comment: tldr; after some research [I don't believe SF supports spaces in columns](https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/Creating+Custom+Fields+in+Salesforce) - there is difference between the actual column name (**API Name**, often containing underscores) and the pretty label/name (**Field Label**, containing spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user2864740 mentioned in the comments above, Salesforce doesn't allow spaces in field api names. In this situation, assuming you are trying to query the standard field with the English label of "Lead Source", the api name is `LeadSource`

[image]

You would want your query to be:

```
sf.query_all("SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE LeadSource = 'Calculator (Website)'")
```